# Need a program that can export flowcharts as xml for later use in JavaApp

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, flowchart

I want to develop a simple way to generate a flowchart for websites.

Here is why I would need something like that:

At first one draws a flowchart in < insert-program-here > and exports it as a xml-file.

This xml-file shall be imported and unmarshalled by another program, which in this case is a Java-application which is nothing more than a graphical interface which a user can use to find his/her way to a specific solution by following the flowchart.

I hope I got it right so far..

Does anybody know a simple program that would export a flowchart as a xml-file so I can use it as mentioned above? Or is there another way that is more comfortable to accomplish my needs?

Thanks for any help!

Best regards.

Comment: I think Enterprise architect can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would recommend yEd because I have had good experiences with it. It uses the XML Format GraphML by default so your users will not have to use an export-Function but can use the files produced when saving their work.

But I don't think one can answer your question with a simple "I recommend program X." because nobody knows what you really need. Maybe one program does not give you all features you want to have for your flowcharts. Maybe others are not cheap enough.

I think you will have to find the right one by yourself. To determine which program can do it for you could check several drawing applications. A list of flowcharting programs can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705476/best-flowchart-software-online-or-offline-preferrably-free). If that is not enough you may use google to find more.